# Retrieving data from an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm trying to get a value from an array used in the Joomla Plugin Hot Propertys. The array is stored in `$this->properties` inside that is group of arrays (sorted by number) and inside each one of them is a key called typeid.

Basically I just need to get the typeid from one of those arrays (for example array 0)

Ive tried `$this-properties->typeid[0]` but it didn't work and I am now stuck.

The contents of the array $this->properties is

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Peace and Tranquility [id] => 60 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 26 Pennygum Place [suburb] => Mariginiup [state] => WA [postcode] => 6065 [price] => 1295000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 5 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>
Set on approximately 3 acres and just 10 minutes to Joondalup CBD this huge family home has it [forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 4 [full_text] => 5 double bedrooms 2 bathrooms, formal lounge and dining, separate study and games. Big chef's kitchen to suit the fussiest of cooks. Air conditioning and loads of extras including a 4 car garage with shoppers entrance. Outisde is a massive shed and a magic pool and entertaining area. Viewing is a must for this stunning property. There's even your own footy pitch. [notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 60 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 1 [homesizerange] => 351+ sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => nexus [auction] => No [agentname] => Steven Pilcher [agentemailaddress] => stevep@nexusrealestate.com.au [agentno] => 0417 908 277 [thumb] => 60_26 Pennygum.jpg [thumb_title] => 26 Pennygum.jpg ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => BRAND NEW TO MARKET!!! [id] => 61 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 24 Windmill Circle [suburb] => Burns Beach [state] => WA [postcode] => 6028 [price] => 1400000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 5 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>
Stunning 5 bedroom 3 bathroom home located in coastal suburb Burns Beach...
[forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 3 [full_text] => Double front door entry into spacious hallway with porcelein tiles and high ceilings.
Study with double aspect windows providing views to the park.
German cabinetry in the powder room with granite benchtops and porcelein sink and tiles.
Activity room, formal dining area, family area and home theatre room.
Ultra modern German kitchen with English granite 1 and a half bowl sink and Italian tapware.
Laundry with access to drying area and garage with a laundry chute connected to family bathroom.
Massive master suite overlooking park and ocean views. Ensuite with double shower and spa with 22 adjustable jets.
Lounge with access to main balcony.
Games with pool tabel as part of sale.
Kitchenette with built in fridge.
Bedroom 2 with access to balcony and massive wardrobe and ensuite with top-of-the-range 24 adjustable jet spa bath.
Main bathroom features a laundry chute.
Bedrooms 3, 4 and 5 overlook the pool and have a triple door wardrobe.
Garage can be triple or double with storage.
Alfresco with plumbing and gas for outdoor kitchen.
Water supply for reticulation or outdoor shower.
9m pool with integral spa jets at the seating area.
Glass pool fence.
Water feature with fibre-optic lighting.
Reverse cycle ducted air conditioning.
[notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 61 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => 597 [storeys] => 2 [homesizerange] => 351+ sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => nexus [auction] => No [agentname] => Pam Gray [agentemailaddress] => pamgray@nexusrealestate.com.au [agentno] => M: 0411 756 455 [thumb] => 61_Windmill_67.jpg [thumb_title] => Windmill_67.jpg ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => For life... not just for Christmas! [id] => 56 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 25 Seaspray Crescent [suburb] => Jindalee [state] => WA [postcode] => 6036 [price] => 750000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => 775000 [bedrooms] => 4 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>
Imagine coming home to sensational ocean views.... [forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 2 [full_text] => The cool sea breeze and firey sunsets that would normally be captured on holiday postcards!! If this is what you've been looking for then stop the search now! This impressive 4x2 loft home is the perfect family residence and is only a few minutes walk from the tranquil blue waters of the Indian Ocean. Call Team Extreme and purchase your slice of paradise!

- With huge street appeal this impressive modern loft home is fully rendered and stands proud on beautifully landscaped gardens.
- The double front entry under a cedar lined porch is most welcoming and the foyer is grand offering wide hallways, a bold stairway to the loft and quality jarrah flooring throughout.
- Spacious master bedroom with walk in robe and a neutral finish. With side access to your private courtyard you can read the Sunday paper in peace. The deluxe en-suite has modern fixtures & finishing's including his/hers vanities, double shower and a separate W/C.
- Three additional double bedrooms all with double built in robes and neutral decor.
- If you're an aspiring master chef you'll love the gourmet kitchen which is complete with upgraded stainless steel appliances, dishwasher, double fridge recess, feature lighting, glass splashbacks & unlimited storage.
- The open plan living and dining is generous in terms of space & style and the separate home theatre is the ultimate place for comfort & relaxation.
- With the convenience of a home study you have the option to work from home should you see fit!
- The main focal point to this stunning home has to be the vaulted loft. This amazing family area is airy and ideal for entertaining with friends. With a built in bar, feature recesses and ambient lighting throughout, it really doesn't get much better than this. From the decked balcony you will be wowed by breathtaking ocean views and surrounding suburbs.
- The alfresco looks out to sparkling below ground pool and with an elevated gazebo you can sit back over lunch and admire your coastal paradise.
- Extras include: ducted evaporative A/C, alarm,
double remote garage with roller-door access to rear, a built in cat-run for all your creature comforts, tinted front windows & masses of storage.
- Call Team Extreme to discuss. [notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 56 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 1 [homesizerange] => 100 - 150 sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => remax [auction] => No [agentname] => Phil Wiltshire [agentemailaddress] => phil@remaxextreme.com.au [agentno] => 0408422863 [thumb] => 56_25 Seaspray.jpg [thumb_title] => 25 Seaspray.jpg ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => SOPHISTICATION & ELEGANCE [id] => 51 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 16 Wessex Street [suburb] => Carine [state] => WA [postcode] => 6020 [price] => 1450000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 4 [bathrooms] => 3 [intro_text] =>
“Individually designed with flair and distinction”.... [forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 3 [full_text] => Architecturally opulent.
Filled with exceptional detailing, from the Casablanca style entrance with sweeping staircase, through to imported Italian floor tiling and ornate recessed ceilings.
A commanding presence, making this a most desirable property.
Located in a sought after suburb with exhilarating views from many vantage points in this home, including views to Carine Open Space.
Neighbouring Triggs magnificent sandy white beaches, Waterman Bays Restaurant and Cafe Strip and Hamersley Golf Course.
Conveniently located to main arteries.
This prestigious home offers sunbathed rooms throughout due to the North/South aspect.

Features:
• Impressive entry with soaring ceilings
• Sweeping staircase
• Gourmet kitchen—with custom cabinetry, pillars, pouter benches, unique stainless steel mosaic backsplash, well designed lighting, island and breakfast bench, and recessed ceilings
• Master retreat housing a massive walk in robe, this sophisticated ensuite includes floor to ceiling
• Italian tiling with deluxe Spa and double vanity
• Luxury Guest Room with own Ensuite
• Spacious study
• Powder room
• Phenomenal dining and entertaining areas
• Laundry with ample storage
• Alfresco entertaining – range hood, timber decking, cedar lined ceilings, down lights, overlooking sparkling pool encompassed in glass fencing
• Outdoor shower with hot and cold settings


Additional Features:
• Pillars in Entrance
• Designer lighting throughout
• Impressive recessed ceilings
• Architecturally designed
• Cedar Shutters throughout
• Claw foot bathtub in main bathroom
• Air conditioning—reverse cycle system on both levels
• Double garage with automatic sectional cedar door & ample storage
• Low maintenance gardens—reticulation
• Two individually designed water features
• Below ground deep blue, crystal clear pool
• Sweeping liquid limestone driveway
• Insulation—covered batts
• Security system
.
Block size 716m2

No stone left unturned, this custom designed residence is filled with a harvest of luxury features!
To cement your viewing phone Heath Dymock on 0411 731 140.
Contact this Agent

Century 21 Coastal Estates Realty - Hillarys
[notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 51 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => 716 [storeys] => 2 [homesizerange] => 351+ sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => century [auction] => No [agentname] => HEATH DYMOCK [agentemailaddress] => hdymock@century21.com.au [agentno] => 0411 731 140 [thumb] => 51_Wessex Street.jpg [thumb_title] => Wessex Street.jpg ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Reduced to Sell [id] => 39 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 78 Quarram Crescent [suburb] => Burns Beach [state] => WA [postcode] => 6028 [price] => 774000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 4 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>

Quality Summit Built home that has never been lived in!....
[forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 2 [full_text] => [notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 39 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => 510 [storeys] => 1 [homesizerange] => 351+ sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => oceanside [auction] => [agentname] => PETER DUGUID [agentemailaddress] => peter@oceansidewa.com.au [agentno] => 0421 905 054 [thumb] => 39_quarram.jpg [thumb_title] => quarram.jpg ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [name] => EXEC-QUISITE [id] => 45 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 84A Jackson Avenue [suburb] => Karrinyup [state] => WA [postcode] => 6018 [price] => 0.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 4 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>

[forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 2 [full_text] => This brand new four bedroom, two bathroom double storey executive home is waiting for its new owners to enjoy all that it has to offer.

Auction Sun 13-Dec-09 11am
AUCTION

Located across from magnificent park lands and only minutes to shops, transport and freeway access.


* Large open plan living, dining and kitchen opening to outdoor alfresco area.
* Two separate living areas.
* Alfresco area ideal for entertaining with large low maintenance lawn and garden.
* Gourmet chef's kitchen with breakfast bar, plenty of cupboard space and stainless steel appliances.
* Large master bedroom with walk in robe and balcony. Picturesque park views from master bedroom and balcony.
* Theatre room.
* Well designed ensuite with double vanity, shower and separate toilet.
* Second bathroom with bath.
* Powder room downstairs for guests.
* Plenty of storage throughout the home.
* Double garage, ducted air conditioning, alarm and more!
* All finishings are to a high quality.
* Green title block





[notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 45 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 2 [homesizerange] => 100 - 150 sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => raywhite [auction] => Yes [agentname] => CANDICE HANNAFORD [agentemailaddress] => [agentno] => 0410 762 445 [thumb] => 45_jacksonave_84.jpg [thumb_title] => jacksonave_84.jpg ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [name] => BETTER THAN SUPERANNUATION [id] => 50 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 15 Trapeze Court [suburb] => Ocean Reef [state] => WA [postcode] => 6027 [price] => 1190000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 4 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>
FABULOUS TWO STOREY, ON A 1033sqm SUB DIVIDABLE, DUPLEX BLOCK.... [forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 3 [full_text] => You must view this amazing home, it has so much more to offer than other homes in this price range. The PANORAMIC OCEAN VIEWS from all levels of this HUGE TRI LEVEL will dazzle you. Packed with so many extra features, plus the FANTASTIC INVESTMENT OPPORTUNITY IT OFFERS, make this is a MUST SEE HOME.

Amazing uninterrupted ocean views
1033m2 duplex block in a whisper quiet cul-de-sac
3 car garage
Separate boat or caravan bay
Can be sub divided without demolishing present home
Approved current plans to build second home on block
Beautiful modern décor
Close to schools
Shops and transport
  [notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 50 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 2 [homesizerange] => 100 - 150 sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => nexus [auction] => No [agentname] => MARGARET FENLON [agentemailaddress] => margaretf@nexusrealestate.com.au [agentno] => 0417 938 656 [thumb] => 50_TrapezeCourt_15.jpg [thumb_title] => TrapezeCourt_15.jpg ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [name] => LUXURIOUS LIFESTYLE!! [id] => 44 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 14 Bernie Rise [suburb] => North Coogee [state] => WA [postcode] => 6163 [price] => 1225000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 3 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>

 This newly built estate in its infancy represents a great opportunity....
[forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 2 [full_text] =>
This newly built estate in its infancy represents a great opportunity, so get in early to view this stunning home built by Buildwise where no expense has been spared and only your presence is required. This property is destined for huge growth so getting in early means that you will reap the rewards when the estate is completely built and settled. With its close proximity to all amenities including beaches, Fremantle and future marina not to mention low maintenance gardens, an abundance of natural light, only one adjoining wall and too many other features to mention, this timeless home is a sure winner.

Contact John Vellutini today for a private viewing.
Contact this Agent

JOHN VELLUTINI, Limnios Property Group - Perth
[notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 44 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 2 [homesizerange] => 100 - 150 sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => limnios [auction] => [agentname] => JOHN VELLUTINI [agentemailaddress] => john@limnios.com.au [agentno] => 0420 371 877 [thumb] => 44_bernie_rise14.jpg [thumb_title] => bernie_rise14.jpg ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [name] => ABSOLUTELY FABULOUS! [id] => 47 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 16 Nias Ramble [suburb] => Iluka [state] => WA [postcode] => 6028 [price] => 859000.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => [bedrooms] => 4 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>
THIS STUNNER HAS EVERYTHING, 10 OUT OF 10 FOR PRESENTATION & DESIGN.... [forsaletype] => Houses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 2 [full_text] => Spacious open plan home with dream kitchen, beautiful bathrooms, separate theatre/games room, double doors to home office & a simply wonderful decked entertaining area with a heated pool & just to complete the perfection, ducted air con & ducted heating. Great street appeal & nothing will come close for great value for this fabulous home.

A MUST TO INSPECT! Call Pam NOW to arrange a viewing 0411 756 455.
Contact this Agent

Pam Gray, Nexus North - Mindarie
[notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 47 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 1 [homesizerange] => 100 - 150 sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => nexus [auction] => No [agentname] => PAM GRAY [agentemailaddress] => pamgray@nexusrealestate.com.au [agentno] => 0411 756 455 [thumb] => 47_nias_ramble16.jpg [thumb_title] => nias_ramble16.jpg ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [name] => 2/69 Sixth Ave [id] => 42 [companyid] => 1 [agentid] => 5 [agentemail] => caleb@redmeetsblue.com.au [agentmobile] => . [user] => 66 [typeid] => 1 [metakey] => [metadesc] => [published] => 1 [approved] => 1 [address] => 2/69 Sixth Avenue [suburb] => Inglewood [state] => WA [postcode] => 6052 [price] => 0.00 [type] => Buy - Homes For Sale [custompricerange] => Auction [bedrooms] => 2 [bathrooms] => 2 [intro_text] =>  


[forsaletype] => Townhouses [commercialpropertytype] => [accommodationpropertytypes] => [carspaces] => 1 [full_text] =>


[notes] => [3dwalkthrough] => Yes [frontpagedetails] => [showhome3dlinkadminonly] => 42 [totalfloorarea] => [landarea] => [storeys] => 2 [homesizerange] => 100 - 150 sqm [tenurecommercialonly] => [builderslogoadminonly] => raywhite [auction] => Yes [agentname] => IAN BLOXHAM [agentemailaddress] => ian.bloxham@raywhite.com [agentno] => 0439 523 321 [thumb] => 42_6thavenue.jpg [thumb_title] => 6thavenue.jpg ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is actually an array of `stdClass` objects.  Each object appears to represent a "hot property", so if `$this->properties` is your array of objects, you can access the `typeid` value of an object using normal array syntax followed by normal object syntax:

```
$this->properties[0]->typeid;
$this->properties[1]->typeid;
```

etc.

As a side note, that block of output you posted is really killing my browser when it tries to do the automatic markup on it  :D

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->properties[0]->typeid
```